Window Screen Frame Sizes
I need to re-make the aluminum frame for a window screen.  In the past, I've used the 5/16" kits from the big orange store, which matched the original frames.
But now I'm replacing a thicker one.  I'm not sure what size I should be shopping for.  It appears the common sizes are 5/16", 3/8", and 7/16".
The old frame measures 0.455" thick.  I checked it at several points along each of the four sides, and it was very consistent.  It's weird though because 0.455" is a smidge more than 7/16".  Is there a standard size fractionally larger than 7/16"?  Or is that overage within the manufacturing tolerance?
These are vinyl new-construction windows manufactured in the early 2000s by a company in California.

I am not sure, but quite a few building product sizes are called to the closest easy size to say.  A smidge over, a half inch under(2x4s)

@crip659: Yes, some materials have "trade sizes" that don't match the actual size.  But I'd never encountered one where the trade size was smaller than the actual size.

I have never seen screen frame stock in a dimension "a smidge more than 7/16". The sizes you mention are the common sizes (there are other, less common sizes as well).
The only potential drawback with using frame stock slightly narrower is a chance for rattling during windy conditions; however, this can be rectified by using one of any number of spring-type tension clips or plastic clips.
I will say that the kits at the "big-box" store, which typically include thin gauge material and plastic corner inserts, result in sub-par screens IMO. You would be better off going to a reputable shop that builds them with minimum .020 gauge stock, quality fiberglass, and metal miter-type corners.

I went ahead and used "7/16-inch" kit, and it fits perfectly, so I'm not worried about rattling in the wind.  Like the original frame, the kit parts are also a smidge over 7/16".  Perhaps it's a coincidence, but the overage is approximately 0.020", which is the advertised gauge of the aluminum.  It's true the kit uses cheap plastic corners, but so do all of my original screens and those have never been a failure point for me.
